# data to structure in vb.net

Tags: arrays, vb.net, string

I have this structure in Visual Basic .net

```
Private Structure queueT
        Public name As String
        Public parent As String
        Public limitat As Integer
        Public maxlimit As Integer
```

And this is the data I get, which I have stored in a one dimensional String array (just pasting 3):

```
!re=.id=*10000B0=name=Up-PBX=parent=Up=packet-mark=pack_pbx=limit-at=256000=queue=PCQ_Up=priority=1=max-limit=512000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=true=disabled=true=comment=PBX

!re=.id=*10000C7=name=Down_Mauro=parent=Down=packet-mark==limit-at=315000=priority=8=max-limit=5000000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=false=disabled=true

!re=.id=*10000C8=name=Down_Mauro_dom=parent=Down_Mauro=packet-mark=pack_Mauro_dom=limit-at=40000=queue=PCQ_Down=priority=2=max-limit=400000=burst-limit=0=burst-threshold=0=burst-time=00:00:00=invalid=false=disabled=true
```

I need to store the information in my structure so it looks like this:

```
queueT.name = UP-PBX
queueT.parent = UP
queueT.limitat = 256000
queueT.maxlimit = 512000
```

I only need the information mentioned above, not the rest. How can I do that?

Thanks!!

Comment: What kind of serialization format is *that*? It doesn't look like any of these. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data_serialization_formats

Comment: Do you have control over the format of the string being sent to you? If so, I would recommend something with readily available parsers to use, like XML or JSON.

Comment: The data I have in my String array is something I get from a Function that I'm using. it's not code it's just a string.

Comment: No I don't have control over it

Comment: Then the person who wrote the serialization code should have also written code to deserialize it. Look for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like it's a key/value pairing after the first value.  From your sample something like this could work.

```
Private Function queueTParse(item As String) As queueT

    Dim queueValues = item.Split("=")
    Dim queueTItem = New queueT

    For i As Integer = 1 To queueValues.Length - 1 Step 2

        Select Case queueValues(i)
            Case "name"
                queueTItem.name = queueValues(i + 1)
            Case "parent"
                queueTItem.parent = queueValues(i + 1)
            Case "limit-at"
                queueTItem.limitat = queueValues(i + 1)
            Case "max-limit"
                queueTItem.maxlimit = queueValues(i + 1)
        End Select

    Next

    Return queueTItem

End Function
```